# Validation Data Type Check going against expectations?

Tags: python

I have included validation in my code in order to ensure only a number can be entered. However when a negative number is entered, the negative number is not accepted by the program as a valid input. How can I solve this? The code is:

```
while QuestionNo != 11:

num1 = randint(0,10)
num2 = randint(0,10)
opp = choice(Operators)
Answer = (input(str(num1) + '' + (opp) + '' + str(num2) + '='))

while Answer.isdigit() == False:
    print ('Please enter a number and nothing else.')
    Answer = (input(str(num1) + '' + (opp) + '' + str(num2) + '='))
```

Thanks,
John Smith

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I check if a string is a number (float) in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/354038/how-do-i-check-if-a-string-is-a-number-float-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `isdigit` method returns True only if all characters in the string are digits. In the case of negative numbers, they start with a dash (-) which is not a digit.

Besides, you are adding some operator and an equals sign to your Answer variable; which are also not digits.

I think the conventional way to test if a string is valid number in Python, is using the `int` builtin:

```
try:
    int(some_string)
    is_valid_number = True

except ValueError:
    is_valid_number = False
```

Comment: [Interesting article](http://pythoncentral.io/how-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-number-in-python-including-unicode/) (very similar answer) showing that numbers in non-English scripts are also handled. Cool!

Comment: Thank you, it worked! And sorry @Jeff Bridgman if this was a similar article (whoops!) >_<